# Open Iterm2 from another terminal app with a list of commands like ls , pwd etc

Tags: shell, sh, iterm2

I want to launch iterm2 from let's say macOS default terminal. with a series of commands like: `cd some/directory/` then touch `a.cpp`.
So how can I do that is there any approach?

I have tried a

```
open -a iterm.app && echo"pwd" && echo "ls" ;
```

but though it opens the iTerm, the command ls and `pwd` only echoes in current shell sessions.

Answer (score 4):

To execute a series of commands in iTerm2 after launching it from the macOS default terminal, you can use the osascript command to run an AppleScript that sends keystrokes to the iTerm2 window. Here's an example:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down' -e 'tell application "iTerm" to tell current session of current window to write text "cd some/directory/"' -e 'tell application "iTerm" to tell current session of current window to write text "touch a.cpp"'
```

This script activates the iTerm2 application, opens a new tab with the t keystroke, changes the directory to some/directory/ with the cd command, and creates a new file named a.cpp with the touch command. You can modify the cd and touch commands to match your specific needs. Note: The osascript command requires macOS's scripting bridge to be enabled. If it's not enabled on your system, you can enable it in the "Security & Privacy" section of System Preferences.